# How to create html based .NET API documentation?

Tags: .net, documentation

How to create html based .NET API documentation? [This is an example](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-sharp-api/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with [ForgeDoc](http://www.forgedoc.com/.). Very easy to use and very attractive price.

Answer (score 1):

I use Doxygen, which supports HTML output with references. I looked into Doxygen as well as Sandcastle, and found Doxygen newer and involves shorter learning curve.

Comment: Yes, Sandcastle is outdated. Support for sandcastle has been discontinued. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create API documentation in [Sandcastle](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10526).
And I believe that you can get an output there which is easily published.